# Properly handle disposable resources in member variables?

Tags: c#, opengl, idisposable, using

I've got a "game class" which looks **rougly** like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenTK;

namespace MyGame
{
    class Game : GameWindow
    {
        Player player;
        List<Enemy> enemies;

        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLoad(e);
            // Initialize stuff here
        }

        protected override void OnUpdateFrame(FrameEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnUpdateFrame(e);
            // Call Update on the player and the enemies
        }

        protected override void OnRenderFrame(FrameEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnRenderFrame(e);
            // Call Draw on the player and the enemies
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var game = new Game())
            {
                game.Run();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But now I've hit a roadblock. The `Player` object and the `Enemy` objects now need to hold references to OpenGL buffers which need to be manually allocated and released. The proposed solution for this kind of thing in C# seems to be to use `IDisposable`. `using` seems to make this convenient when you're just keeping it inside one method. But how do you solve this the best way if you keep it as a member variable?

Comment: Is it possible to wrap the buffers in a managed object? Typically an IDisposable is used to wrap the unmanaged resource, and is implemented in such a way that your other classes won't have to propagate the IDisposable interface all the way up your inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how you mean. What is a managed object? Could you give me a code example?

Comment: Basically, managed means created by .NET, and therefore under control of CLR. So the OGL buffers are unmanaged. The solution is not so much code as design. If possible, you'll want a class, say `OGLBufferWrapper`, that will implement `IDisposable`. This will handle everything to do with the buffer. Then in your `Player` and `Enemy`, anything needing the buffer will do `using(var buffer = new OGLBufferWrapper(){...}`. If you cannot work out a way to do this, you may have to implement `IDisposable` all the way up your object hierarchy.

Comment: Filling up the buffers is really slow though, so I want to keep them between calls.

Comment: In that case you may just have to implement IDisposable on your other objects (as @Amit's answer demonstrates)

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are looking for this:

```
class Game : GameWindow, IDisposable
{
        private bool _disposed;

  public void Dispose()
        {
            // If this function is being called the user wants to release the
            // resources. lets call the Dispose which will do this for us.
            Dispose(true);

            // Now since we have done the cleanup already there is nothing left
            // for the Finalizer to do. So lets tell the GC not to call it later.
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

 /// <summary>
        ///     Dispose client here
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing"></param>
        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!_disposed)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    if (your_any_managed_unmanaged_resource != null)
                    {
                       //do cleanup
                    }
                }

                _disposed = true;
            }
        }
}
```

Call Your Game

```
Game g = new Game();
g.Play();

g.Dispose();
```

Comment: Ooh, I just realised that GameWindow is already an IDisposable.